# При подключении к терминальному серверу через xfreerdp файлы сохраняются после закрытия сессии

Tags: linux, ubuntu

При подключении к терминальному серверу через xfreerdp файлы на флешке сохраняются только после выхода из сессии.
Система ubuntu server 16.04.02 в качестве тонкого клиента
Подключение флешки `xfreerdp /drive:USB_DISK,/media/flashka` 
Монтирование флешки  `mount -t vfat -o rw,codepage=866,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 $path_mount_flash /media/flashka/`
Редактируем файл(ы) на флешке можем его закрыть открыть данные будут, если вытащить и опять вставить данных нет. Если просто закрыть сессию на терминальном сервере то данные на флешке сохраняются.

Answer (score 0):

Надо при монтировании usb флешки использовать опцию sync, тогда запись на флешку будет происходить постоянно

```
  mount -t vfat -o rw,sync,codepage=866,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022 $path_mount_flash /media/flashka/
```